# Dynamic generate column mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I try to make a ListView with dynamic generation of column. I use mvvm patern. 
How i can implement this? 
In this momemt I have only static columns.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ProblemProducts}"
                  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="4">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Spisujący" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding _spisujacy}" Width="auto"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Miejsce składowania" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MiejsceSkladowania}" Width="auto"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Typ spisu" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding _typSpisu}" Width="auto"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Kod" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Kod}" width="auto"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can create `GridView` with appropriate columns dynamically using converter. Here is working example:

[image: App screen shot]

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:WpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        d:DesignHeight="189" d:DesignWidth="312" Width="300" Height="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <WpfApplication1:ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter x:Key="ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" View="{Binding ColumnConfig, Converter={StaticResource ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter}}"/>    
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ColumnConfig ColumnConfig { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Products = new List<Product> { new Product { Name = "Some product", Attributes = "Very cool product" }, new Product { Name = "Other product", Attributes = "Not so cool one" } };
            ColumnConfig = new ColumnConfig { Columns = new List<Column> { new Column { Header = "Name", DataField = "Name" }, new Column { Header = "Attributes", DataField = "Attributes" } } };
        }
    }

    public class ColumnConfig
    {
        public IEnumerable<Column> Columns { get; set; }
    }

    public class Column
    {
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public string DataField { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Attributes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter.cs

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var config = value as ColumnConfig;
            if (config != null)
            {
                var gridView = new GridView();
                foreach (var column in config.Columns)
                {
                    var binding = new Binding(column.DataField);
                    gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn {Header = column.Header, DisplayMemberBinding = binding});
                }
                return gridView;
            }
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +100 if I could too. So good I've made up an example implementing this (and also adding sorting of the dynamically added columns) and pushed it to GitHub at https://github.com/9swampy/DynamicPropertyPropertiesListGridViewExample

Comment: Another theoretical +100 from me.  I can't believe it took me so long to find how to do this, and it's so much cleaner than other implementations.

Comment: I know it's been years, but how do I go about adding context menu to the view, or context menus to each column, with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Sergei, for a marvelous answer.

I used it in a slightly different form, since I needed to add columns with non-text datatypes.

So the following modification to Sergei's answer allows you to have ContentControl wrappers on the data values. They will then be rendered according to the DataTemplates defined for the values in each cell.

The column will be wrapped if ContentControlDataField is used rather than TextDataField (originally DataField):

```
    public class ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        var config = value as ColumnConfig;
        if (config != null) {
            var grdiView = new GridView();
            foreach (var column in config.Columns) {
                bool cc = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(column.ContentControlDataField);
                var binding = new Binding(cc ? column.ContentControlDataField : column.TextDataField);
                if (cc) {
                    var template = new DataTemplate();
                    var fact = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentControl));
                    fact.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, binding);
                    template.VisualTree = fact;
                    grdiView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn {Header = column.Header, CellTemplate = template});
                } else
                    grdiView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn {Header = column.Header, DisplayMemberBinding = binding});
            }
            return grdiView;
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

public class ColumnConfig {
    public IEnumerable<Column> Columns { get; set; }
}

public class Column {
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string TextDataField { get; set; }
    public string ContentControlDataField { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: your code seems to be what I need cause I need a checkboxcolumn, but I don't really understand what to put in the Column.ContentControlDataField in order to do what I need, can you help me?

Comment: Thanks for your code - I had a go at using it. Do you happen to know why changes at runtime to ColumnConfig are not refreshing the view? I changed Columns to an ObservableCollection [edit: think it works now, I was missing some OnPropertyChanges on my ViewModel]