# Creating Dynamic nested GridView

Tags: c#, wpf

I have following Class structure -

```
public class Details
{
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string Serial { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}

public class Summary
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public List<Details> Details { get; set; }
}
```

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274731/dynamic-generate-column-mvvm) link to structure this requirement.

My Requirement is like having a `GridView` with dynamic no of columns which will be mapped by List of `Summary` class. Now Header will be mapped with `GridViewColumn` header. Till now it is fine. Now from `Details` property, I want to create again a child `GridView` having dynamic no. of columns mapped with List of `Details` class and Rows defined in `Details` class properties. Can any one tell me correct solution.

**Edit** Link updated

**What I tried Yet**

```
public class DynamicGridViewConverter: IValueConverter
{

    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dynamicConfig = value as List<Summary>;

        if (dynamicConfig != null)
        {
            var gridView = new GridView();
            foreach (var lineColumn in dynamicConfig)
            { 
                DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();
                FrameworkElementFactory frameworkGrid = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
                FrameworkElementFactory frameworkListView = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ListView));

                GridView internalGridView = new GridView();

                GridViewColumn col1 = new GridViewColumn();
                col1.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Customer");
                col1.Header = "Customer Header";
                internalGridView.Columns.Add(col1);

                GridViewColumn col2 = new GridViewColumn();
                col2.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Serial");
                col2.Header = "Serial Header";
                internalGridView.Columns.Add(col2);

                GridViewColumn col3 = new GridViewColumn();
                col3.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Model");
                col3.Header = "Model Header";
                internalGridView.Columns.Add(col3);

                frameworkListView.SetValue(ListView.ViewProperty, internalGridView);

                var itemSourceBinding = new Binding();
                itemSourceBinding.Source = lineColumn.Details;
                frameworkListView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, itemSourceBinding);

                frameworkGrid.AppendChild(frameworkListView);

                template.VisualTree = frameworkGrid;                    gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn() { Header = lineColumn.Header, CellTemplate = template, Width=200});
            }
            return gridView;
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

It is showing `View Can not be shared by more than one ListView`

What part I am missing?

Comment: What is your issue? Can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: @MichaelEakins: Please check [This Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ebae2b91-83bb-40a4-98b0-bfb277e04a2c/nested-dynamic-gridview).