# CheckBox rendered as a Label

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox, mvvm

I have a dynamically generated ListView, that uses data binding to allow editing some `Boolean` values through CheckBox. I use a IValueConverter to generate the ListView's columns  (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274731/dynamic-generate-column-mvvm) answer):

```
public object Convert (object Value, Type EntryType, object Parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture)
{
    var Config = Value as ColumnConfig;
    if (Config != null)
    {
        var GridView = new GridView ();
        Binding NameBinding = new Binding ("Name");
        GridViewColumn BaseColumn = new GridViewColumn { Header = "Settings", 
                                                       DisplayMemberBinding = NameBinding,
                                                       Width = 125,
                                                       CellTemplate = new DataTemplate ()};
        GridView.Columns.Add (BaseColumn);

        foreach (Column CurrentColumn in Config.Columns)
        {
            Binding NewBinding = new Binding (CurrentColumn.DataField);
            FrameworkElementFactory FEF = new FrameworkElementFactory (typeof (CheckBox));
            FEF.SetBinding (CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, NewBinding);

            GridViewColumn GVColumn = new GridViewColumn
                                            {
                                              Header = CurrentColumn.Header,
                                              DisplayMemberBinding = NewBinding
                                            };
            var DTemplate = new DataTemplate ();
            DTemplate.VisualTree = FEF;

            GVColumn.CellTemplate = DTemplate;

            GridView.Columns.Add (GVColumn);
        }

        return GridView;
    }

    return Binding.DoNothing;
}
```

Which is used like so in the XAML:

```
<ListView Margin="2" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LineHighlightListView}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding InMatrixList}"
              View="{Binding InMatrixColumns, Converter={StaticResource ConvertItemsToDynamicGridView}}" />
```

The columns' headers are generated elsewhere. The code should take in a `ColumnConfig` items, and create `GridViewColumn` objects that have a `ChechBox` databound to some other value elsewhere. However, all I am getting is columns with text in place of the CheckBoxes. The text is correct, so the data binding is valid, but the `FrameworkElementFactory` object is not working as expected.

**Why are the checkboxes rendered/converted to textboxes?**

Comment: This is a really bad way of doing it. Use MVVM and data templates instead

Comment: @Glen Thomas I am already using MVVM. I don't think there is a way to do this correctly with DataTemplates, is there? The DataTemplate would apply to all cells, including the first column which is text-only.

Comment: Do you feel like you're going down a rabbit hole?  Because you're going down a rabbit hole.  Create a custom control, or a usercontrol, that manipulates the UI in the codebehind based on the state of the objects it is bound against.

Comment: @Will After trying that solution, I still don't see how you'd do it without doing most of the above - the only change being that I am doing it in the codebehind, rather than in a converter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule: **avoid that way to dynamically compose a template**.

I had a similar problem and I have solved as follows:

```
    //see: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/444371/Creating-WPF-Data-Templates-in-Code-The-Right-Way
    private static DataTemplate CreateTemplate(UniprogCellVM cell)
    {
        var tcell = cell.GetType();

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("<DataTemplate DataType=\"{{x:Type local:{0}}}\">", tcell.Name);
        sb.Append("<local:UniprogCellControl ");
        sb.Append("Content=\"{Binding Path=.}\" ");
        sb.Append("Header=\"{Binding Path=.}\" ");
        sb.AppendFormat("Style=\"{{DynamicResource Root{0}BoxStyleKey}}\" ", cell.Interaction);
        sb.Append(">");

        sb.Append("</local:UniprogCellControl>");
        sb.Append("</DataTemplate>");

        var context = new ParserContext();

        context.XamlTypeMapper = new XamlTypeMapper(new string[0]);
        context.XamlTypeMapper.AddMappingProcessingInstruction("local", tcell.Namespace, tcell.Assembly.FullName);

        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("local", "local");

        var template = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(sb.ToString(), context);
        return template;
    }
```

Basically, you should compose a fully-valid XAML of your template, then parse it with the parser.

Since the text-composition is a trivial task, you may pass any parameter in the creation function (as in my example above).

Just a final note: this approach is useful, but requires a computational effort because the runtime parsing and compilation. Avoid a large number of items created in such way.

Comment: Well, that is an issue (the table would have ~100 elements, and there would be a few tables that use this system). I guess I will follow @Will's advice and stop going down further down the rabbit's hole. I will just do an UserControl that deals with this in the code behind.

Comment: 100 elements aren't a problem at all. I'm using this approach for a super-specialized grid having hundreds of cells (that's an "element" for me), mostly have a rather complex UI. I mean you should avoid this approach for many thousands of cells.

Comment: Nope, that's unnecessary because the function above generates a DataTemplate instance which is injected directly to a ContentControl. Of course, you might pre-calculate (i.e. compile) the templates whereas the application faces a well-defined layout. In my case it isn't. However, have a try with a test program, just to realize how is performing this approach.