# Customizing wpf listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Is any easy way to create wpf listview that depends on class injected in?
I want to have such functionality:

```
class Class1 
{
   int prop1 {get; set;}  
   int prop2 {get; set;}  
   int prop3 {get; set;}  
}
...
ListView<Class1> lv;
```

And list view with 3 columns is created automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic generate column mvvm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274731/dynamic-generate-column-mvvm)