# binding a generic property of a model in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, generics, mvvm

I have a wpf usercontrol which has binding to a model(CustomerTaxModel) and it has a listview and GridView which should display data of property of type "T" Assets below. This type T is a class with only properties and it has variable number of properties depending on the data we receive from third party tax verification company.

```
public class CustomerTaxModel

{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public T Assets { get; set; }


}
```

My Generic type "T" classes looks like below. They may not have matching properties. I should display data of this type T with property names in one column and their values in second column. Is that possible to do this type of binding in xaml ? The type T takes CorporateAsset , AgricultureReturns etc..

```
public class CorporateAsset
{        

    public string CorporateOfficeName { get; set; }

    public string NetWorth { get; set; }

    public string Subsidized { get; set; }

    public string LaunchDate{ get; set; }

}


 public class AgricultureReturns

{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string FieldSizeinAcres { get; set; }

    public string CropType { get; set; }

    public int NoOfSeasons { get; set; }

}
```

One solution I tried was binding to a KeyValuePair variable instead of binding the type "T" directly which works. .I referred the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274731/dynamic-generate-column-mvvm) and I tried with static property class in place of type T and it shows the data dynamically but when property itself is generic how can we display its properties in grid view.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:WpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    d:DesignHeight="189" d:DesignWidth="312" Width="300" Height="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <WpfApplication1:ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter x:Key="ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataClass}" View="{Binding ColumnConfig, Converter={StaticResource ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter}}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

`Binding.Path` works by reflection. It can look up any public instance property the actual runtime object has. This is how the [`DataContext` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx) of WPF controls can be of type `Object`. Your `Assets` property could be object as well as far as WPF is concerned, but there's no reason to forgo strong typing in your models. WPF eats anything.

This gives me a `TextBlock` that says "Fred":

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = new CustomerTaxModel<AgricultureReturns>()
    {
        Assets = new AgricultureReturns() { Name = "Fred" }
    };

}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Assets.Name}" />
```

If you've got an `ObservableCollection` of `CustomerTaxModel`, a common pattern is to have a bunch of `DataTemplates` for the different types that `Assets` might be. These are pretty lame templates, but you get the idea.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TaxModels}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <!-- DataTemplates in Resources will be used here automagically -->
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Assets}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type models:AgricultureReturns}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FieldSizeinAcres}" />
                <!-- etc -->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type models:CorporateAsset}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CorporateOfficeName}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NetWorth}" />
                <!-- etc -->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: But the xaml binding you have specified above still needs us to specify the T class property names (e.g.  "{Binding Assets.Name}" ) explicitly ? Just by binding the datacontext can it not iterate through list of properties and dynamically display them ?

Comment: @krrishna See update. There's no standard way to have WPF automagically figure out what properties you have and display them. You *could* give CustomerTaxModel a collection of a "named property with value" thing, with a different subtype for int, string, etc. -- and display an ItemsControl of those with templates applied implicitly as above. Unless you have a large number of potential Asset types, I wouldn't go there.