# DataTemplate binding checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate, dynamic-columns

**my problem:**

I need to set up the databinind of my checkboxex by code, but those Checkboxes are into a DataTemplate to be apply to a listview with dynamic columns,I got it working, but I don't like the way I did, because it breaks with my dynamic columns concept in my Listview, now I do create a DataTemplate for every possible column in my Listview, all the dynamic columns will be CheckBoxes, so I guess some how I can create only one DataTempleate and not many like I did now

**my code:**

I have a class like this:

```
public class CArea
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool[] items { get; set; }

    public CArea()
    {
        items = new bool[3]; //this is the dynamic,every field will be a column
        items[0] = true;
        items[1] = true;
        items[2] = false;
    }
}
```

I need to bind an ObservableCollection Areas in a ListView with dynamic Columns, in this sample 3 items but can be 4,2,5 or anything, the dynamic generation of columns problem it's ok with a converter (thanks to [Dynamic generate column mvvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274731/dynamic-generate-column-mvvm/11278187)), my problem is the binding of the CheckBox for every item in the Areas's collection, now I'm writing a xaml like this

```
<Window.Resources>
        <!--<datagridDinamico:ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter x:Key="ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter" />-->
        <local:ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter x:Key="ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Chk0" DataType="{x:Type GridViewColumn}">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding items[0]}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Chk1" DataType="{x:Type GridViewColumn}">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding items[1]}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Chk2" DataType="{x:Type GridViewColumn}">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding items[2]}" />
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Areas}" View="{Binding ColumnConfig, Converter={StaticResource ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter}}"/>
```

One template for every `items[i]` but it's awful and destroy the dynamic concept of my listview. The converter code is this:

```
public class ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var config = value as ColumnConfig;
            if (config != null)
            {
                var grdiView = new GridView();
                foreach (var column in config.Columns)
                {
                    bool usaTemplate = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(column.ContentControlDataTemplate);
                    var binding = new Binding(usaTemplate ? column.ContentControlDataTemplate : column.TextDataField);
                    if (usaTemplate)
                    {
                        Window window = Application.Current.MainWindow;
                        DataTemplate template = (DataTemplate)window.FindResource(column.ContentControlDataTemplate);
                        grdiView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = column.Header, CellTemplate = template });

                    }
                    else
                        grdiView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = column.Header, DisplayMemberBinding = binding });
                }
                return grdiView;
            }
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }



        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I took the DataTemplate from the column config object,... and that is not quite nice because I need to set it up by hand in the viewmodel, like this

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public ColumnConfig ColumnConfig { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<CArea> Areas { get; set; }
        public ViewModel()
        {
            Areas = new ObservableCollection<CArea>() {
                new CArea {Id=1, Name = "Area 1" },
                new CArea(){Id=2,Name="Area2" } };
            ColumnConfig = new ColumnConfig
            {
                Columns = new List<Column>
                {
                    new Column { Header = "Area",   TextDataField = "Nombre" }
                }
            };
            Categorias = ServCategory.GetAllPossibleColums();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var c in Categorias)
            {
                ColumnConfig.Columns.Add(new Column() { Header = c.Nombre, ContentControlDataTemplate = "Chk"+i.ToString()});

                i++;
            }
        }

        private List<CCategoria> categorias;
        public List<CCategoria> Categorias
        {
            get { return categorias; }
            set { categorias = value; }
        }
}
```

Well that's all, I hope you can help me,

Thank you for your time

Comment: `DataType` of a `DataTemplate` should be a view-model type actually. But I see that you create `DataTemplate`s using `GridViewColumn` as `DataType`. This is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: How do you identify what the checkboxes mean in the application?  I think you have tried to simplify the situation too much for the question.  I suspect the problem here is in the design of your Model

Comment: dymanoid, I really don't understand what do you mean, can you please give me more detail?

Comment: Chad, You are right, I 'm not happy with my aproach, that's  why I am asking for Ideas about  the implementation of this scenario, how to implement a dymamic- columns listview  with Checkboxes inside.

Comment: Please read carefully [about data templating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) and how to use this feature. The property is called **Data**Type, not **View**Type. So setting this property to a value of `{x:Type GridViewColumn}` is fundamentally wrong, because `GridViewColumn` is a type of a **view** representation, not of the **data** this data template represents.